# Мониторинг Redis-server в zabbix

Tags: redis, zabbix

Нужно снимать статистику с *редиса*.

*Редис* крутится там же, где и *заббикс*.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это сделать.

Comment: на сайте *zabbix-а* [ссылаются](https://share.zabbix.com/cat-db/db-redis/redis) на этот [проект на *github-е*](https://github.com/blacked/zbx_redis_template).

Comment: я поставил сей шаблон ранее. мне не подходит

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решил вопрос готовым шаблоном для заббикс, с использованием node.js [ссылка на гитхаб](https://github.com/blacked/zbx_redis_template)